# How my robots.txt should look like for a single page app

Tags: robots.txt, ajax

I can understand how to disallow bots to crawl some pages/folder in normal application. For example for [google-bot it is nicely described here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en).

But what should I do if I have a single page application (the one that uses only ajax to upload new content and has routing and page generation on the client). How to make it crawlable is described [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en) and [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/), but what if I do not a bot to follow some links (that are on my starting page)? By this I mean the following:

When SPA is loaded for the first time it loads some basic HTML. This html can have specific links like:

- home  (#!home/)
- about (#!about/)
- news (#!news/)

but I do now want a bot to crawl #!about link.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "but what if I do not a bot to follow some links?" does not make much sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: @edvinas.me I modified my question. May be this makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to do exactly what I want. It is nicely [documented by google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174993):

> When your site adopts the AJAX crawling scheme, the Google crawler
>   will crawl every hash fragment URL it encounters. If you have hash
>   fragment URLs that should not be crawled, we suggest that you add a
>   regular expression directive to your robots.txt file. For example, you
>   can use a convention in your hash fragments that should not be crawled
>   and then exclude all URLs that match it in your robots.txt file.
>   Suppose all your non-indexable states are of the form
>   '  #DONOTCRAWLmyfragment. Then you could prevent Googlebot from crawling these pages by adding the following to your robots.txt:
>
> Disallow: /*_escaped_fragment_=DONOTCRAWL

Comment: an example would be nice